# Calculating NDVI percentage change in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, ndvi, sentinel-2, map-algebra

I am trying to show how NDVI changed between two periods using raster calculator in QGIS. I stumbled upon one example that was done in ArcGIS which i have no access to but would want to do the same in QGIS.

The example used the formula shown below

`Con("S2_NDVI_2015" < 0,-1,1) * (("S2_NDVI_2018" - "S2_NDVI_2015") / "S2_NDVI_2015" * 100)`

How can i use a similar formula in QGIS?

Note: I already calculated the NDVIs for the two time periods.

Comment: @Kazuhito I have tried to adapt the expression with my data but i am getting weird values in the output still with negatives (-45.52-241.13). What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Your result looks fine. The output can be negative number where your "S2_NDVI_2015" is greater than  "S2_NDVI_2018".

Comment: @Kazuhito, I thought this should have at least 100 as maximum value. From your experience, is 241.13 realistic for NDVI change?

Comment: Let's say you've got NDVI (0.8) in 2018 and (0.2) in 2015, then (0.8 - 0.2)/ (0.2) * 100 = 300. It's a huge change, though.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this expression:

```
(-1) * ("S2_NDVI_2015@1" < 0) * (("S2_NDVI_2018@1" - "S2_NDVI_2015@1" ) / "S2_NDVI_2015@1") * 100 + ("S2_NDVI_2015@1"  >=  0) * (("S2_NDVI_2018@1" - "S2_NDVI_2015@1" ) / "S2_NDVI_2015@1") * 100
```

[image]

Which comprises two parts:

(1) When a pixel on "S2_NDVI_2015@1" is negative (<0), it will multiply (-1) factor and the following terms.

```
(-1) * ("S2_NDVI_2015@1" < 0) * 
     (("S2_NDVI_2018@1" - "S2_NDVI_2015@1" ) / "S2_NDVI_2015@1") * 100
```

(2) When a pixel on "S2_NDVI_2015@1" is not negative (>= 0), it will simply calculate following terms.

```
("S2_NDVI_2015@1"  >=  0) * 
     (("S2_NDVI_2018@1" - "S2_NDVI_2015@1" ) / "S2_NDVI_2015@1") * 100
```

[image]